# Group by several columns and add values from last column to list

Tags: python, pandas

I have this table:

| id | type | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | inv_num | 123 |
| 1 | company | ASD |
| 1 | item | fruit |
| 1 | item | vegetable |
| 2 | inv_num | 123 |
| 2 | company | FOO |
| 2 | item | computer |
| 2 | item | mouse |
| 2 | item | headphones |

I would like to group the same types in one row in a list format:

| id | type | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | inv_num | 123 |
| 1 | company | ASD |
| 1 | item | ['fruit', 'vegetable'] |
| 2 | inv_num | 123 |
| 2 | company | FOO |
| 2 | item | ['computer', 'mouse', 'headphones'] |

Is it possible to do it using 'groupby'?

Comment: If you want a list only for groups of more than one item: use `lambda x: list(x) if len(x)>1 else x` as aggregation function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need lists only if length of values greater like `1` use custom lambd function in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
f = lambda x: x.tolist() if len(x) > 1 else x
df = df.groupby(['id','type'])['text'].agg(f).reset_index()
print (df)
   id     type                           text
0   1  company                            ASD
1   1  inv_num                            123
2   1     item             [fruit, vegetable]
3   2  company                            FOO
4   2  inv_num                            123
5   2     item  [computer, mouse, headphones]
```